# Restrict Asset Library Access to certain user group

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, asset-library, image-rendition

Is there a way to restrict a certain user group from getting the full size image in SharePoint?

I have a user group called View Only Users, and set them to view only capability for my asset library.

When the View only User logs in, they can see all the thumbnails but cannot download. But they can still right click on the image, and see the full image anyway.

I'm trying to prevent these group of users from seeing the full size image, unless they are given permission to a particular image. Is this achievable in SharePoint?

Example: Show them the thumbnail image even if they right click and view that image.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to prevent these group of users from seeing the full size image if the group of users have view only permission on it.